# Reset figure numbering

Tags: numbering

I define the `MyChapter` as a newcounter for my chapters. I use the

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\theMyChapter.\arabic{figure}}
```

for figure numbering. I works correctly up to chapter 3, but from chapter 4 it does not reset the figure numbers. For example if I have 3 figure in chapter 3, the first figure of chapter 4 is number 4.4 and the second one is numbered 4.5 (it means it does not reset). What should I do?

Edited:
The document seems like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,headsep=1cm, inner=3cm, outer=3cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xepersian}

%%%%%%%%% Chapter Counter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{MyChapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theMyChapter.\arabic{equation}}
\numberwithin{figure}{MyChapter}
\def\MyChapterNumbering{\ifcase\theMyChapter صفرم\or یکم\or دوم\orدهم \fi }
\def\MyChapterNumberingg{\ifcase\theMyChapter  یکم\or دوم\or سوم\or چهارم\or دهم \fi }
\long\def\MyChapter#1{\setcounter{equation}{0}
\newpage
\vglue5cm
{\topicfont\small\noindent فصل \MyChapterNumberingg \\ \vglue1cm \noindent\large #1}
\vglue2cm
\noindent{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{فصل \MyChapterNumberingg : #1}
\stepcounter{MyChapter}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    

\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DefaultMathsDigits

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

 \MyChapter{test1} 

 \MyChapter{test2}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}`

Comment: With an uptodate TeX Distribution you can use `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}`  without an additional package.  With older distributions you have to load package `chngcntr`.   Macro `\numberwithin` is provided by package `amsmath`.

Comment: @marmot It works, Tanx. But I have another problem. I want to put the chapter number before figure number.

Comment: @esdd It seems that  `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}` dosen't work in my distribution, and since I use `amsmath` the `numberwithin` is suitable. But as I asked in the previous comment, what should I do if I want to change the position of chapter and figure numbers.

Comment: To answer this, we would need a complete but *minimal* document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. How would @esdd know you're loading `amsmath`?

Comment: Also we do not know how the counter `Mychapter` is defined and what the purpose of its definition is. It could also be that you want to use `\numberwithin{figure}{MyChapter}` ...

Comment: You are right. I add the document as an edit in the question.

Comment: It seems the problem is solved by the  commands `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\theMyChapter.\arabic{figure}}`and `\setcounter{figure}{0}` together. Thanx for all suggestions.

Comment: Just for the records: you could achieve the same with a much less hacky code. Are you doing this just to have your own (?) chapter numbers?

Comment: @marmot I try other codes, but because of using `xepersian` package they were all useless. Indeed, my complete code has other sections and parts such as header which should be changed .Nevertheless, other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments.